iText with pdfcalligraph gives Not a valid Unicode code point: 0xFFFFFFFF
When there is a table with column header containing Latin letters between two Arabic segments, and with using Rubik font, there is an exception.
If the text has all Arabic or Latin, or if Arial Unicode is used, the error doesn't happen.

iText: 8.0.5
pdfcalligraph (typography): 4.0.2
Java 22

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "license.json"));

    var header = List.of("عنوان IP للمستخدم", "كلمة المرور", "اسم المستخدم");

    try (var out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("out.pdf"));
         var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(out));
         var document = new Document(pdf)) {

      var fontPath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(
          "font/Rubik-Regular.ttf");

      if (fontPath == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
      PdfFontFactory.register(fontPath.toString());

      var font = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont("rubik", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

      var tableWidth = pdf.getDefaultPageSize().getWidth() -
          document.getLeftMargin() - document.getRightMargin();
      var table = new Table(header.size());
      table.setWidth(tableWidth);

      for (var column : header) {
        var cell = new Cell();
        var paragraph = new Paragraph(column)
            .setFont(font);
        cell.add(paragraph);
        table.addCell(cell);
      }

      document.add(table);
    }
  }

The exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid Unicode code point: 0xFFFFFFFF
    at java.base/java.lang.Character$UnicodeScript.of(Character.java:8907)
    at com.itextpdf.typography.shaping.Shaper.splitArabicGlyphLineIntoWords(Shaper.java:977)
    at com.itextpdf.typography.shaping.Shaper.applyArabicScript(Shaper.java:373)
    at com.itextpdf.typography.shaping.Shaper.applyOtfScript(Shaper.java:224)
    at com.itextpdf.typography.shaping.TypographyApplier.applyOtfScript(TypographyApplier.java:57)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TypographyUtils.applyOtfScript(TypographyUtils.java:101)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TextRenderer.applyOtf(TextRenderer.java:801)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.applyOtf(LineRenderer.java:1357)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.layout(LineRenderer.java:160)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.directLayout(ParagraphRenderer.java:222)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.layout(ParagraphRenderer.java:87)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.getMinMaxWidth(ParagraphRenderer.java:682)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.getMinMaxWidth(BlockRenderer.java:1092)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.calculateMinMaxWidths(TableWidths.java:639)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.autoLayout(TableWidths.java:95)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.layout(TableWidths.java:84)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.calculateColumnWidths(TableRenderer.java:1844)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.applyMarginsAndPaddingsAndCalculateColumnWidths(TableRenderer.java:1981)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.layout(TableRenderer.java:302)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:120)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.createAndAddRendererSubTree(RootElement.java:347)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.addElement(RootElement.java:357)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:85)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:119)
    at TableTest.main(TableTest.java:51)

